# Access object of tab bar controller item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have 4 tab bar item. Each of them will have its own navigationController within it. I am trying to set a property of tab(1) rootViewController from tab(2). How do I get the instance of tab1(rootVC) class back?

Answer (score 0):

i think use this line.....

```
[[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you

```
[[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Comment: I believe OP is not trying to switch tabs. But trying to get back the object of the tab class so that he/she can set it's properties.